React.js Dynamic fields in modal form won't update
My form input fields inside of a Modal will not change (state). While I try to edit the form, the focus goes off from the field and targets the modal's x button. I am using Flowbite Modal if that matters.
This is how I set the fields for the form:
const [formChange, setFormChange] = useState(false);
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    productName: "",
    productDescription: "",
});
const { productName, productDescription } = formData;

The form is dynamic. Basically I display a table with edit button for each item in the table row and whenever clicked, it opens a modal with input fields that display the items information, such as name and description.
However, when I try to edit a field nothing happens visually. I've tried to console.log the result and it logs the first character that I type along with the preset name, but will not update the input field. Then when I type another letter, it returns the original value and the next letter that I typed. For example "Product 1" will print out as "Product 1g" if I type g on the keyboard and if I press h afterwards, it just shows "Product 1h" in the console only, but not in the input field.
The issue could be that the form fields are dynamically set in useEffect hook like this:
useEffect(() => {
    if (formChange === true) {
        let table = selection.toLowerCase(); // A state for dropdown for different item categories
        let content;

        switch(table) {
            case "products":
                content = (
                    <>
                        <div>
                            <TextInput
                                id="productName"
                                name="productName"
                                value={productName}
                                onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event, "productName")} />
                                {/* Same for description and other fields */}
                        </div>
                    </>
                );
                break;
            }

            setModalContent(
                <>
                    {/* Other items */}
                    <Modal.Body>
                        {content}
                    </Modal.Body>
                </>
            );

            setOpenModal(true);
        }
    }, [formChange]);

The formChange state is set to true in handleModal, which is fired after clicking the edit button. It basically just transfers the item information to the modal.
For the input change I have tried several different approaches for this function, but currently input change handler looks likes this:
const handleInputChange = (event, fieldName) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    console.log(fieldName, value);
    setFormData(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [fieldName]: value
    }));
};

What is wrong with this approach, is it because the content is dynamically rendered inside of an useEffect hook or is there something else I'm missing out?

I think you also need to add formData as your useEffect dependency:
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [formChange, formData]);


I already did that, it kinda worked but kinda did not. I found a post stating that the Flowbite Modal has a bug and needs to be reworked. Changing onChange to onBlur and value to defaultValue helped, but you had to double click on a form field in order to gain the focus and while pressing tab on keyboard it focused on the modal's X button only.
https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-react/issues/701
